# I'm trying to make an animated header where the logo goes up until it leaves the screen

Tags: css, react-native, react-animated

I'm passing the header component through the router and I used the code below to change the color of the header as I scroll:

```
const yOffset = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
   const headerOpacity = yOffset.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 600],
    outputRange: [0, 1],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: headerOpacity,
      },
      yOffset: yOffset,
      headerBackground: () => (
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(30, 30, 30)',
            ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
            opacity: headerOpacity,
          }}
        />
      ),
      headerTransparent: true,
    });
  }, [headerOpacity, navigation])

    <Animated.ScrollView
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
          }
          onScroll={Animated.event(
            [
              {
                nativeEvent: {
                  contentOffset: {
                    y: yOffset,
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
            {useNativeDriver: true},
          )}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}>
```

How can I change things like the `margin` or `position` in the header using this code?

In this case, what I need to change is the second child of this header. I will pass the code of the header below

```
<>
    <S.Header backColor={selectBackColor()}>
      {type === 'return' ? (
        <S.HeaderToggleButton onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
          <S.HeaderBackButtonImage
            source={require('../../assets/seta_voltar_topo.png')}
            resizeMode={'contain'}
          />
        </S.HeaderToggleButton>
      ) : (
        <S.HeaderToggleButton onPress={handleToggleHeader}>
          <S.HeaderToggleButtonImage
            source={
              isOpen
                ? require('../../assets/menu_sanduiche_fechar.png')
                : require('../../assets/menu_sanduiche.png')
            }
            resizeMode={'contain'}
          />
        </S.HeaderToggleButton>
      )}
      <S.LogoTextAling>
        {type !== 'return' && (
          <S.PovoLogo
            isHome={type === 'home'}
            source={require('../../assets/op_mais_novo_logo.png')}
            resizeMode={'contain'}
          />
        )}
        {title && !isOpen && (
          <S.TitleText isTypeReturn={type !== 'return'} isOpen={isOpen}>
            {title}
          </S.TitleText>
        )}
      </S.LogoTextAling>
    </S.Header>
  </>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to interpolate header position based on scroll  offset.

```js
<Animated.View
  style={{
    opacity: yOffset.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 300],
      outputRange: [0, 1],
      extrapolate: "clamp",
    }),
    position: "absolute",
    zIndex: 999,
    transform: [
      {
        translateY: yOffset.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 300],
          outputRange: [-200, 0],
          extrapolate: "clamp",
        }),
      },
    ],
  }}
>
  <S.Header backColor={selectBackColor()}>
    {type === "return" ? (
      <S.HeaderToggleButton onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
        <S.HeaderBackButtonImage
          source={require("../../assets/seta_voltar_topo.png")}
          resizeMode={"contain"}
        />
      </S.HeaderToggleButton>
    ) : (
      <S.HeaderToggleButton onPress={handleToggleHeader}>
        <S.HeaderToggleButtonImage
          source={
            isOpen
              ? require("../../assets/menu_sanduiche_fechar.png")
              : require("../../assets/menu_sanduiche.png")
          }
          resizeMode={"contain"}
        />
      </S.HeaderToggleButton>
    )}
    <S.LogoTextAling>
      {type !== "return" && (
        <S.PovoLogo
          isHome={type === "home"}
          source={require("../../assets/op_mais_novo_logo.png")}
          resizeMode={"contain"}
        />
      )}
      {title && !isOpen && (
        <S.TitleText isTypeReturn={type !== "return"} isOpen={isOpen}>
          {title}
        </S.TitleText>
      )}
    </S.LogoTextAling>
  </S.Header>
</Animated.View>
```